# How can I make linechart values on every grid line

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart lib with v3.0.1.
And I have 7 values in every week day to show on LineChart with below image.

How can I set every value on xAxis grid line?

every labels values in IAxisValueFormatter are :

0.0         Thu 
1.1666666   Fri 
2.3333333   Sat 
3.5         Sun 
4.6666665   Mon 
5.833333    Tue 
6.9999995   Wed

my chart setting as below:

```
chart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
chart.setPinchZoom(false);
chart.setDescription(null);
chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
xaxis = chart.getXAxis();
xaxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
xaxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
xaxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(true);
legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
```

every data set as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
    float usageTime = 0;
    entries.add(new Entry(i, usageTime));
}
LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, p.getName()); // add
// entries to dataset
dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
dataSet.setLineWidth(2);
dataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
dataSet.setColor(ColorTemplate.rgb(hexColor[colorPosition]));
colorPosition += 1;
dataSets.add(dataSet);
```

show data as below:

```
LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
chart.setData(lineData);
chart.animateX(500);
chart.invalidate();
```

[image]

[image]

But if I use points more than grid lines, it's draw what I except.
[image]

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit method `public void renderGridLines(Canvas c)` in `XAxisRenderer.java`. Put value you want into `float[] positions`.
`position[i]` is x-value, `position[i+1]` is y-value

Make `positions` is same data set array. Referring snippet drawing chart's value

```
LineData lineData = mChart.getLineData();

for (ILineDataSet set : lineData.getDataSets()) {

    if (set.isVisible())
        drawDataSet(c, set);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your propose ans. But I've a little curious why if points more than grid line, it's correct?
I update my quest to add img.

Comment: Increase positition array size equal  number of points, put all drawing value into it

Comment: Got it! it wouldn't force to set label count!